# Do I have to say if the face-down card I'm playing is a trap or spell, or is it enough to place it in the trap/spell zone?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Am I obligated to tell my opponent whether the card I'm playing is a trap card or a continuous spell card that's placed face down, or is it enough to just place it in that zone and say "I'm playing a card face down"? Am I obligated to be specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to state if it is a spell or trap card when you set a card face down, it just must be legal in the zone you are setting in. This is actually done with spell cards to bluff traps and make your opponent pause to think about what you could have, and what it could mean for them with their plays.

Comment: True, no need to say what it is. In fact, there are some monsters that can be set aa trap cards. It's part of some game strategies, so no need to tell that to your opponent.